# how to solve a iterative substitution equation?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

So I'm struggling with a question, I need to find the time complexity of this equation using iterative substitution, Now I understand how to expand the equation however I do not know how to find the time complexity using it. I know the answer is `o(n^log2 3)`.

```
T(n) = 3T(n/2) + O(n)
```

I've expanded from about here, what do I do next?

```
3^3T(n/2^3) + 3^2(n/2^2) + 3n/2 + n
```

What do I do next to reach the answer of `o(n^log2 3)`?
Can someone please explain this to me step by step?

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved like this:

```
T(n) = 3T(n/2) + O(n)

     = 3(3T(n/4) + O(n/2)) + O(n)

     = 3^2(T(n/4)) + O(n)

     = 3^4(T(n/8)) + O(n)
```

Note `O(n/4) + O(n/2) + O(n)` is still `O(n)`

```
let n = 2^k

then T(n) = 3^(k-1) + O(n)

          = 3^(log(n) - 1 ) + O(n) // log(n) is log (n) to base 2

          = O( n^log(3) ) because n^log(3) > n
```

Comment: hi where did the log come from? in the second part?

Comment: if `n = 2^k` and you take `log` on both sides you get, `log(n) = k`